# Can an electric circuit do recursion?

Tags: theory

Can an electric circuit do recursion?

By recursion I mean any kind of recursion, tail, binary, nested, etc: http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/recursion/whatisrecursion/section2.rhtml

By electric circuit I mean a simple board without any special chips, just wires, resistors, diodes, capacitors etc.

Comment: I guess feedback could be thought of as a kind of recursion...  but "recursion" is an algorithmic construct, a circuit isn't.

Comment: What is a "special chip" ? I would think that anything that involves feedback would be considered recursive.

Comment: @efox29 a programmable microchip for example or a CPU, stuff you can't make at home.

Comment: @Majenko so in general it's impossible to have algorithms in simple circuits?

Comment: @kuhaku Well, an algorithm is a set of discrete steps. The closest you get to that in a simple circuit is propagation delays through different parts of it.

Comment: @kuhaku Also, a CPU is just a large collection of transistors. With enough patience (and transistors) you can make one at home.  Google "Homebrew CPU with Transistors"

Comment: That's pretty cool. I'm more of a computer science guy so my electronics knowledge is very limited. @Majenko

Comment: I agree with @Majenko feedback could be thought of as recursion without a terminating condition (without the worry of a stack overflow;)

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig can't feedback cause overheating?

Comment: @kuhaku it's not the feedback that will cause overheating, it is watts (U * I) over any given component. If you feed a 1W resistor more than one watt, it will overheat. (NB: I am not an Electronics Engineer, so this is only my understanding. I'm sure someone can correct / provide more insight)

Comment: Negative feedback is commonly used in op-amp circuits and is nothing to do with overheating.

Comment: I've done the Lorenz attractor (chaos) with an analog circuit.  It needs opamps and multipliers.

Comment: "Recursion", in the programming sense, requires storage.

Comment: @HotLicks isn't there an electrical equivalent of storage? like capacitors?

Comment: @kuhaku - I mean "memory" -- "state" of some sort.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First we need to decide what recursion really is. When you take a recursive function, there may exist a transformation that gets rid of the recursion, but introduces *state*. In other cases, the transformation will have to introduce *both* state *and* iteration. So, writing a function out recursively is a way of making state and possibly iteration *implicit*, as opposed to *explicit*. In other words, recursion is just a way of writing out the thing.

The state *is there anyway*, you're just not explicitly putting it down on paper. In languages such as C, recursive function calls usually store their state on the stack.

Now, any circuit that has *state* (stored charge, energy, etc.) - and that will be all of them, really - is, by definition, recursive. No iteration necessary :)

Concretely, let's work on a first-order IIR filter. Its output can be given by a recursive function. Given an input signal `x(t)`, the output `y(x(t), t) =  a1*y(x(t-1), t-1) + b0*x(t)`, where `a1` and `b0` are constants that parametrize the response. This is in discrete time - `t` is an integer with the unit of a number of clock cycles.

The C implementation, assuming `t>=0` and `x(-1) == 0`, would be:

```
float a1, b0;

// Recursive, Implicit State
float y(float (*x)(int), int t) {
  return t != 0 ? a1 * y(x(t-1), t-1) + b0 * x(t) : b0 * x(t);
}

// Non-Recursive, Explicit State
float y(float (*x)(int), int t) {
  static float y_prev = 0.0;
  if (1) { // optional to ensure correct use only
    static int t_prev = 0;
    assert(t_prev == t-1 || t == 0);
  }
  return y_prev = a1 * y_prev + b0 * x(t);
}
```

The code can be also be implemented as a first order switched-capacitor infinite impulse response filter.  You can certainly *build* such a system:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyXdNd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

SW1 flips twice in each clock cycle. With values shown, for 12 bit accuracy the clock is limited to 10kHz due to R4-C1 time constant. U1, U2, U3 are voltage followers - say op-amps configured for gain=1.

If we set `a1=(1-b0)`, and transform this to a continuous time differential equation, we can get the "same" (continuous) response with an RC circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCwPHv.png)</sup>

Here, T is the clock period of the clock feeding the switched capacitor circuit above, and U1 is a voltage follower.

When the frequencies of interest are limited to ~1/10th of the clock frequency, both the continuous-time and the discrete-time (switched capacitor) circuits respond the same.

Both circuits, and the code, can be modeled by a recursive function, also known as [*a recurrence relation*](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Low-pass_filter#/Discrete-time_realization).

Comment: If one could balance two capacitors perfectly, and had switches with no parasitic capacitance, series resistance, leakage, or other unwanted effects, one could build an arbitrary-precision DAC which would accept signals in LSB-first format.  For each step, charge an "input" cap to VDD or ground, then connect it to the output cap.  The most singificant bits of the output voltage after some number of steps will be the last few bits clocked to the device.  Of course, practical considerations would limit *useful* precision to far less than that of a conventional DAC, but the concept is still cute.

Comment: @supercat AFAIK, a vacuum-isolated circuit (or even an air-isolated one) could have precise capacitors, and balancing them to 1ppm using an impedance bridge is not extraordinarily hard. You could probably do it just fine in the 60s at the latest. As for the switch, you don't need a capacitance-free device, just a constant-capacitance device. I think that a 16-bit DAC could be demonstrated that way, using air capacitors and a mechanically-actuated switch. With a few tiny dielectric spacers, made of a good material, between the large plates, their dielectric absorption could be kept at bay.

Answer (score 12):

What that page calls "linear recursive" can be done to some extent in hardware, where it's called *successive approximation*. The example of Newton-Raphson is a good one as it's quite close to how analogue gun director computers worked.

But generally it's a bad idea to adapt programmer's intuition (based around executing a series of instructions) to electronic circuits (based around continuous flow).

Answer (score 4):

I made one back in 2003, in simulation at least. It was part of an EU funded project called poetic, which in short was making an FPGA that could reprogram itself for evolvable hardware purposes. (Alas the fabrication went off track a bit.)

At the suggestion of the designer Yann, I made a growing delay line. The CPU would poke one cell of our FPGA asking for a delay line N units long. This would create a single unit then poke an adjacent cell and ask for a delay N-1 units long, etc. The units could be anywhere on the chip and formed connections to one another with a hardware implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm, IIRC. When it was all connected you could start using the delay line.

Not an efficient way to create one, but definitely recursion.